# Replace asp:Image relative path (../../images) with absolute path on another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config

i have a web application and all of its images are relative path,
for example `'../../images/logo.png'`,

i need to change all of the images in the application to another domain,
for example : `'static.domain.com/images/logo.png'`

is there a fast way to change all the data ? 
of course the long option is to iterate all images and change them manually,

Comment: Why don't you do a find and replace (ctrl + H) and replace "../../images/" with 'static.domain.com/images/' risky but should be the easiest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Replace all occurrences manually
- Use custom image class, inherited from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`, to make possible configuration of behavior regarding image path

Answer (score 0):

In general you should encapsulate relative paths to resources in a code block, like this (using an ASP.NET MVC example as my classic ASP.NET skills are gettting rusty):

```
<%= Url.Content( "~/images/logo.png" ) %>
```

To map them to a different path than the default, you can either define a custom route that matches all *.png files (and any other used formats) or introduce your own helper extensions so that you can rewrite the above to something like this:

```
<%= Url.Static( "~/images/logo.png" ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is like @TBohnen.jnr said

> Why don't you do a find and replace
>   (ctrl + H) and replace "../../images/"
>   with 'static.domain.com/images/' risky
>   but should be the easiest?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a httmhandler for handling .png files, and change their address there.
another way is to press ctrl+f and find and replace ../../ with your new address in entire solutions which takes a minute.